# Chrome dev tools - Timeline API

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

do you know if there is anyway to access timeline through somekind of API? I would like to run some JS code which would start recording events, then stop it and save HAR to my database via post ajax call.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [chrome.debugger api for extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/stable/extensions/debugger.html)

or

[remote debugging protocol](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging)